Combining multiple point layers in a heat map not by density of specimens but by density of species
I'm trying to combine multiples point layers in a heatmap but I'm not sure that a heatmap is the best solution for my use.
Each point layer correspond to locations of specimens for 1 specie. For some point layers, there are a lot of locations and sometimes for others, a lot less. I'd like to combine them to know where are the locations that have the richest diversity but for the moment, I only succeed to have the locations that have the most of specimens, all species considered.
Could you help me?



Merge all input layers into one layer.
Extract its extent, buffer it some, create a grid with the buffered layer as extent.
Join attributes by location (summary): fields to summarize = your species field, summaries to calculate = unique. This will add a species count field to the grid layer with number of unique species in each grid cell.

You can symbolize this layer:

And/or

Create centroid points. Then symbolize the centroid layer with the species count as weight:


